# Get Value input multi rows Yii

Tags: yii, rows, tabular

How do I pass a form value to the controller, `actionCreate function ()` specifically. Exemplifying. I have the following code in the form:

```
    <tbody class="templateTarget">
    <php foreach ($ items as $ i => $ item):?>
    <tr class="templateContent">
    <td>
    <php echo $ form-> textField ($ item, "[$ i] name", array ('style' => 'width: 100px'));?>
    </ td>
    <td>
    <php echo $ form-> textField ($ item, "[$ i] description ', array (' style '=>' width: 100px '));?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type = "hidden" class = "rowIndex" value = "<? php echo $i;?>" />
    <div class="remove"> <php echo Yii:: t ('wm', 'Remove');?>
    </ td>
    </tr>
    <php endforeach;?>
```

I have a form where I use to create tabular input multiple rows where I have a button to add a new line, I need to know how many rows were filled by this is that the problem presented above.
 Well if you can pass the value of the variable $ i help me a lot.

Thank you.

Comment: You really need to dive into the Yii documentation.  Read about model/view/control (mvc).  It seems like you don't understand how yii is supposed to work.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.overview

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand, but I think you mean that you have a JavaScript function which adds new `templateContent` rows to your table, and you want to know how to get the `$i` value to do this?

Here is a tip: the $i value in Yii's tabular input **does not actually need to be the next true `$i` value - it can be any integer number you want as long as it's unique**.

On the server side, in your POST action that processes the form, you will be looping through the $_POST variables, yes? I'm not sure what kind of model `$item` is, but if it's we type `Item` then you will loop through the `$_POST['Item']` array.

As long as the JS (or PHP AJAX call) that generates the new form fields uses a unique number all of the data will be POSTed and you can save it. I use the PHP `time()` function to generate the $i values.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might need this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table
It basically sums up the methods on how to collect tabular inputs. Check it out. Hope it helps :)